# Mount point attachment on remote machine using ansible

Tags: server, ansible

- I am trying to add a mount point to a remote machine using ansible.
- The mount point that has to attached there is a folder of another server.
- I wrote following ansible script to do that but it hanged and no response.

```
- hosts: all
  remote_user: deepcompute
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  tasks:
  - name: Adding SSH key
    authorized_key:
        user: deepcompute
        state: present
        manage_dir: yes
        key: "{{lookup('file','/home/deepcompute/personal/test_class/data.pub')}}"

  - name: Adding mount point in fstab
    lineinfile:
        path: /etc/fstab
        line: "user@machine1.servers.nferx.com:/home/deepcompute/hpcentraldata/ /example_mount/ fuse.sshfs _netdev,user,idmap=user,transform_symlinks,identityfile=/home/deepcompute/.ssh/id_rsa,allow_other,default_permissions,reconnect,ServerAliveInterval=20,ServerAliveCountMax=5,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0"

  - name: Mount Directory Example
    file:
      path: /example_mount
      state: directory
    notify:
        - Change Permission

  handlers:
  - name: Change Permission
    file:
        path: /example_mount
        owner: user
        group: user
        state: directory
    notify:
        - Add mount point

  - name: Add mount point
    mount:
        path: /example_mount
        src: user@machine2.servers.nferx.com:/home/deepcompute/hpcentraldata
        fstype: ext4
        state: mounted
        opts: bind
```

So In above script , i will create a mount point in a new server.

Comment: hello, please read this page and add elements to your post https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, also provide infos on logs, or anything that will help us undestand you. Can you achieve your mountage to work without ansible first ?

Comment: Yes , i could mount , without using ansible. It works.

Comment: try @vladimir code, the point is you don't need `lineinfile` because `mount` module will handle everything. Plus: your handler 'Add mount point' may not be fired, because it's only triggered when there's a change (see https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/10735)

Answer (score 1):

Use [mount](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/mount_module.html#mount-control-active-and-configured-mount-points) module.

```
- mount:
    src: 'user@machine1.servers.nferx.com:/home/deepcompute/hpcentraldata/'
    name: '/example_mount/'
    fstype: 'fuse.sshfs'
    opts: '_netdev,user,idmap=user,transform_symlinks,identityfile=/home/deepcompute/.ssh/id_rsa,allow_other,default_permissions,reconnect,ServerAliveInterval=20,ServerAliveCountMax=5,uid=1000,gid=1000'
```